# Проблема при добавлении данных в HBase (python)

Tags: python, hadoop

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Вот такой код для mapper.py для работы с HBase:

```
#!/opt/anaconda/envs/bd9/bin/python

import sys
import happybase


def db_conn():
    try:
        connection = happybase.Connection('server')

        raise ValueError('Something went wrong!')
        sys.stdout.write('We have connection with DB!')

        connection.open()

        table = connection.table('table')

        if not table:
            connection.create_table(
                    'table',
                    {
                        'cf1:url': dict(max_version=4096),
                    })

            sys.stdout.write('DB create!')

            map()
        else:
            sys.stdout.write('Start parse lines')

            map()

    except ValueError as e:
        pass


def emit(uid, timestamp, url):
    sys.stdout.write('{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(uid, timestamp, url)


def emit2(uid, timestamp, url):
    try:
        table.put('uid', {'cf1:url': 'data:url'}, timestamp=int(timestamp)*1000)
        raise ValueError('Something went wrong!')
    except ValueError as e:
        pass
    else:
        table.send()


def map():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        objects = line.strip().split('\t')
        if len(objects) == 3:
            uid, timestamp, url = objects
            if len(uid) > 1 and len(url) > 1 and url.startswith('http') and int(uid) % 2 == 0:
                emit(uid, timestamp, url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db_conn()
```

При запуске кода получаю такую ошибку:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
viktor.andriychuk@bd-master:~/task2$ vim mapper.py
viktor.andriychuk@bd-master:~/task2$ cat part-00000 | ./mapper.py > out.txt
  File "./mapper.py", line 41
    def emit2(uid, timestamp, url):
      ^
```

Comment: добавьте весь код, этот полностью рабочий

Comment: спасибо за ответ. добавил код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли одну закрывающиеся скобку

```
def emit(uid, timestamp, url):
    sys.stdout.write('{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(uid, timestamp, url) #здесь должно быть две скобки а у вас одна
```

Comment: Вы были правы. А я искал ошибку, связанную с emot_2 (